# how can i stop/pause the storyboard that have started on WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, storyboard, controls

I moving the train image along to railway.In my storyboard, I will begin many animation. I want to stop or pause the storyboard anytime.

I tried to many way to stop/pause the animation. I begin the storyboard like below.

```
myStoryboard.Begin(this, true);
```

My full code is below.

```
Storyboard sb;
    public mimic_screen()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        sb = new Storyboard();

    }

    public bool move(Image target, double oldX, double oldY, double newX, double newY, int time)
    {
        try
        {

            DoubleAnimation anim1 = new DoubleAnimation(oldY, newY, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(time));

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim1, new PropertyPath("(Canvas.Top)"));

            Storyboard.SetTarget(anim1, target);

            sb.Children.Add(anim1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Move Function Error:"+ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void begin()
    {
        sb.Begin(this,true);
    }
    public void pause()
    {
        sb.Pause(this);
    }
    public void resume()
    {
        sb.Resume(this);
    }

    public void stop()
    {
        sb.Stop(this);
    }
```

The begin function work clearly. But when I call other functions(stop/pause/resume) nothing happens. When I debug, methods fire successfully. Where is my mistake?

Comment: As already said, don't use a Storyboard at all. Call `target.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, anim1)` instead. To stop the animation call `target.BeginAnimation(Canvas.TopProperty, null)`.

Comment: I try this way but nothing happened again. I think It's not the source of the problem. Thank you for your time.

Comment: hey ! remove `this` and use just `sb.Pause()` it will work it works for me ...also only sb.Begin() is enough ..

Comment: @RaoHammasHussain i tried this way too. Nothing happened.Thanks for your time.

Comment: Hi everyone, I called stop/pause function from other class, so it didn't work. I edited my code. I putted a button and I use stop/pause functions from click event. It's now clearly work.